# AS3 - Have a label selected for input

Tags: actionscript-3, label

I have a label inside of an image that pops up when users click a button.

I would like the label to already be "selected" for keyboard input. The current implementation requires users to click inside of the label area before they can begin typing keyboard input.

Is there any way I can set the label to be "selected" and ready for input without requiring the user to click inside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the focus on the label field:

```
stage.focus = labelField;
```

your label must be `input` type and `mouseEnabled` and `selectable` set to `true`.